# What is the text commonly found at the end of documentaries called?

Tags: terminology

In documentaries / semi-documentaries and even fake documentaries there's often text that comes on at the end showing some facts fading in and out, or where the people are now (depending on subject).

Is there a term for this element of a video? I tried searching for "end text in documentary" but couldn't really find anything except actual credits.

Comment: I don't recall a formal cine term for this, but traditionally in literature an "epilogue" would serve the same purpose.Perhaps "epitaph", or some fused term I just made up "epiText".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might even be more on-topic at English.SE, but as far as I'm concerned that's definitely called an [epilogue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epilogue#In_film).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epilogue#In_film):

> In many documentaries and biopics, the epilogue is text-based, explaining what happened to the subjects after the events covered in the film.

Comment: Hmm feel like I should've known that. Do you know if filmmakers use any term for the design of this section? I tried searching youtube for documentary epilogue and still only find music. I'm trying to find examples of different styles to get a better idea of what I think is most effective.